# XGBoost Regressor gives a flat prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, xgboost, forecasting

I'm working on a XGBoostRegressor model to predict crypto prices. I trained the model with a year of data for a 15 minutes candlestick (almost 36000 datapoints). I also added some lag features (Simple moving averages). The Target variable is the Close price for a 15 minutes candlestick.

There is an unexpected behavior with the model predictions. For some parts of the time series, it seems to follow the price successfully but for other parts of the time series the model predictions seems flat as shown in the following image:

[Model Predictions vs Test Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FedX.png)

Why does this behavior happened with XGBoost prediction?
What can I do to get a better result?

This is the code I've used:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = price.drop(columns=FEATURES_TO_DROP)
y = price[TARGET]

# Train-test split for validation
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=False)
xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor()
params = {
    'n_estimators': 300,
    'max_depth': 5,
    'learning_rate': 0.2,
    'colsample_bytree': 0.6
}

best_model = xgb.XGBRegressor(**params)
best_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = best_model.predict(X_test)

# Calculate RMSE on the test set
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print(f"Test RMSE with Tuned Model: {rmse}")

# Plot actual vs. predicted values on the test set
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
plt.plot(y_test.index, y_test, label='Actual')
plt.plot(y_test.index, y_pred, label='Predicted')
plt.plot(y_test. index, X_test['SMA_5'], label='SMA5')
plt.title('Actual vs. Predicted Stock Prices')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[Feature importance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytvyj.png)

Comment: What was the minimum stock price in your training set?

Comment: @BenReiniger The minimum stock price in training set is 0.2228

Answer (score 1):

Try to train on "relative changes" and not on absolute values. If you use absolute values, you inherently limit your model to a range where you train it. If you use relative changes with time there is no absolute scale in your prediction.

However, there is no simple answer to your question. The performance of predictions depends a lot on the exact goals you want to achieve. There is no silver bullet.